# Stored Procedure with Optional Parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a View that grabs a lot of data that I want to be able to Search through.  The View is set up with the following columns:

> Part_Number, Description, Information, Supplier, Manufacturer, Category, Subcategory, Currency, Price, Discount.

I am looking to create a Stored Procedure which lets me search through the View for the data I am specifically looking for.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM PartsData
WHERE Part_Number = '0010.05.20.20'
```

Now my first thought, was to set up the procedure so that the only parameter it was looking for was a `VARCHAR` which would essentially contain whatever the entire `WHERE` clause was.  This sounds like it would work.

However, would I be able to instead set up a Stored Procedure with optional parameters?  I am not sure if this is something you can do in SQL though.

If not, is my initial idea for implementation my best bet?  Because it seems like there should be a better way to go about doing this. :\

Sometimes the `WHERE` clauses can be rather long, such as:

```
WHERE Description LIKE '%cap' 
AND Supplier LIKE 'A2A Systems' 
AND Manufacturer LIKE 'Vario'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't create a proc on a view, but instead just use the proc against the underlying query itself.

In your example you use `LIKE` instead of `=` which adds a level of complexity to the mixture. Usually this could be handled like:

```
WHERE 
(Description = @desc or @desc is null)
AND (Supplier = @supplier or @supplier is null)
AND (Manufacturer = @manufacturer or @manufacturer is null)
```

With `LIKE` you'd have to concatenate the `%` on the head and tail end (or just one end if that suffices). [Brent has a post about performance about LIKE](https://www.google.com/search?q=like%20sargable&oq=like%20sargable&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1903j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```
WHERE 
(Description like '%' +  @desc + '%' or @desc is null)
AND (Supplier = '%' + @supplier + '%' or @supplier is null)
AND (Manufacturer = '%' + @manufacturer + '%' or @manufacturer is null)
```

Lastly, this is commonly referred to a kitchen sink query, or catch all query. [Here's Aaron's blog about performance with this type of query.](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is dynamic SQL: the ability to dynamically build a query based on different parameters.

A few great starting points include:

- [Kitchen Sink Procedures by Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) - how to write a query when your users might be asking for anything out of a huge table
- [Dynamic Search Conditions by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - which goes into more depth
- [Curses and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - but don't read this until you've read the above two, because dang, it goes into even more details
- [Dynamic SQL by Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/dynamic/) - if you prefer learning with slides and following along with Stack Overflow's database, there's this (disclaimer: I wrote it)

One thing to look out for, though, is that anytime you pass end user inputs into a database query, you can be vulnerable to SQL injection. A few resources on that:

- [SQL Injection in Microsoft Books Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017) - pretty good one-page summary of what the problem is, and how to look out for it.
- [SQL Injection Attacks: Is Your Data Secure by Bert Wagner](https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/sql-injection-attacks-is-your-data-secure/) - video from GroupBy
- [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) - classic XKCD comic about the problem of SQL injection. I only mention this because the other resources are all going to refer to Bobby Tables, and you're going to wonder why everyone's laughing.